# Search for historical balance sheet data

Tags: historical-data, fundamentals, value-investing

I would like to run backtests on swedish companies.

How I can retrieve historical balance sheet data?

Comment: You need to access an International Accounting Database. There are several https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2938675 they may be expensive unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size of the company. Large companies publish an annual report in which the annual financial statements are also included.
If the company is large enough, it is also possible to obtain information from the regulatory authorities, but this usually costs money.

Alternatively, you could ask the company itself.